# How to read JNDI value from Java code?

Tags: java, websphere, jndi, keystore

I have a Java code that load a key store which is defined inside a runtime (.war file).

```
 KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
 File key = new File ("/was85/resources/security/ecommerce_gr_mobile.p12");
 trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(key), "Pass".toCharArray());
```

However, I don't need to hard code the key store - pass . I need to grab them from the running EAR because those values are different across our environments (DEV - QA- UAT and PROD).

I read that I need use something like this:

```
Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();  
InputStream inputStream =     
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/web.xml/worklight.properties");  
properties.load(inputStream); 
String keystore= properties.getProperty("ssl.keystore.path");
```

However, the value inside the worklight.properties is the default one and not the one that we defined inside the runtime

worklight.properties:

```
ssl.keystore.path = /conf/default.keystore
```

JDNI value inside the runtime:

[image]

How can I grab the one defined in the JNDI and not the default one?

**Edited:**

Web.xml:

```
<env-entry>
        <description>[OPTIONAL] SSL certificate keystore location. Default: conf/default.keystore.</description>
        <env-entry-name>ssl.keystore.path</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value/>
    </env-entry>

    <env-entry>
        <description>[OPTIONAL] SSL certificate keystore type. Valid keystore types: jks, PKCS12. Default: jks.</description>
        <env-entry-name>ssl.keystore.type</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value/>
    </env-entry>

    <env-entry>
        <description>[OPTIONAL] SSL certificate keystore password.Default: worklight.</description>
        <env-entry-name>ssl.keystore.password</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value/>
    </env-entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in `web.xml` you have `env-entry` like this (maybe add your web.xml to the question):

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>ssl.keystore.path</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>/conf/default.keystore</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

in that case you should access it either via annotation, like this:

```
@Resource(name="ssl.keystore.path", type=String.class)
private String filePath;
```

or via `InitialContext`:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
String filePath = (String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/ssl.keystore.path");
```

Comment: I tired the second option, but I got an exception that there is no "ssl.keystore.path" in "java:comp/env"

Comment: @HussamEddin Please add your `web.xml` as it is hard to guess your configuration.

Comment: Added the web.xml. As you can see, I can't see the value "/was85/.../ecommerce_grs_mobile.p12

Comment: @HussamEddin You need to provide values in  `<env-entry-value>`

Comment: This value needs to be empty and I can't hard coded it as it is different between environments. It should be read from the JNDI. I need to read it from the Worklight instance and not from the hard coded.

Comment: @HussamEddin InitialContext example works for me, so you had to code it incorrectly somehow.

Comment: your solution works if you set the configuration as WebSphere variables or as resource environments providers. In my case, the value that I need to read is inside a web module which is running inside the container of Worklight and there is no way we could read it. So I had two choices even to set it up in the JVM and use System.getProperty or I set it up as resource environment provider and use InitialContext.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could resolve the issue is by

1. Adding JNDI entry named `"ssl.keystore.path.AppName"` Inside the
   websphere JVM which has the path for my keystore.
2. Adding JNDI entry named `"ssl.keystore.Pass.AppName"` Inside the
   websphere JVM which has the value for my keystore Password.

Inside My java code I used:

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
String keystorePath = System.getProperty("ssl.keystore.path.AppName");
String keystorePass = System.getProperty("ssl.keystore.Pass.AppName");
```

and the main code became:

```
File key = new File (keystorePath);
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(key), keystorePass.toCharArray());
```

Comment: This has nothing with JNDI, its just JVM system property.